# Geometric reason why elliptic curve group law is associative

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

The question title says it all.

> I am looking for a geometric proof for the fact that the group law defined on elliptic curves is associative.

I've heard somewhere about something on the internet about 2 cubics intersecting at 8 points must have a ninth point in common but I've never understood what that meant. Maybe this is what I'm looking for.

If a well-known reference has this result and I could easily find it in a library (or better yet over the internet, which I did not manage to find), then I'd accept this as an answer too.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Take a look to page 6 of http://web.math.ku.dk/~kiming/lecture_notes/2000-2001-elliptic_curves/grouplaw.pdf

Comment: @JeanMarie : Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

There is a geometric proof of associativity in the  elementary undergraduate book by Silverman and Tate [*Rational Points on Elliptic Curves*](http://books.google.fr/books?id=mAJei2-JcE4C&pg=PR8&lpg=PR8&dq=tate+silverman&source=bl&ots=MvvlWHLtd6&sig=-sCJ_g-uLJvwagXuuIamUFvd0KU&hl=fr&ei=WT2rTtauEuOI4gS2udDZDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q&f=false).
The proof there is indeed along the lines you suggest of considering a pencil of cubics with nine base points, and is illustrated by a nice drawing.
The textbook derives from 1961 lectures by Tate, one of the best specialists ever in elliptic curves (he received the  prestigious Abel prize in 2010).

Comment: I was writing my answer while Adam posted his: the book I refer to is *not* the one by Silverman alone mentioned by Adam.

Comment: Ah, I see there was a modification to Adam's post: so it *is* the same book after all! The confusing point is that Silverman wrote alone the more advanced book *The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*, where however he proves associativity only algebraically, not geometrically.

Comment: Yeah, Silverman's more advanced book is beautiful, but not at all appropriate for undergraduates.  His undergraduate book with Tate, however, is amazingly accessible.  I've never taught a course with it, but I have a colleague who has several times, and the (not very well prepared) students really liked it.

Answer (score 5):

This is contained in any intro book on elliptic curves.  Here are two ones which are accessible to undergraduates:

1. McKean and Moll, "Elliptic Curves: Function Theory, Geometry, Arithmetic".
2. Silverman and Tate, "Rational points on elliptic curves"