# defining the group law on elliptic curves in general

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra, elliptic-curves

Let $k$ be an arbitrary field and $C \subset \mathbb{P}^2(k)$ an elliptic curve. In order to define the group law on $C$ we need to establish some geometric facts first, e.g.

- Any line intersects $C$ at exactly three points (counting multiplicity).
- For any point $p \in C$ there is a unique line intersecting $C$ at $p$ with multiplicity 2 (tangent line at $p$).

If $C$ is given by a (homogeneous) Weierstrass equation $Y^2Z = X^3+aXZ^2+bZ^3$ these facts could be shown by elementary calculations without many difficulties. However, if $\operatorname{char} k \in \{2,3\}$ the general equation for $C$ is more complicated, and the calculations will become quite cumbersome.

I am looking for a reference, where the group law on elliptic curves as well as the proof of associativity is treated in full generality, and which avoids cumbersome calculations. Instead, such geometric facts should be derived by methods of algebraic geometry. Furthermore, it would be nice if this could be done within classical algebraic geometry (i.e. by examining the coordinate ring of $C$) since I am not quite familiar with the theory of schemes yet.

Comment: After posting my answer noticed [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76813/geometric-reason-why-elliptic-curve-group-law-is-associative?rq=1). Answers include references.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, you might have a look at the description of the group law in terms of [divisors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_(algebraic_geometry)) on the curve. This makes use of more advanced (but still classical) machinery to preclude painful verifications of associativity, etc. One reference would be Shafarevich's [Basic Algebraic Geometry I](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540548122). The relevant information begins in III.3.1, and III.3.2 features the group law. (You might want to read/skim from the beginning of III, depending on how familiar you are with divisors.)

After introducing divisors and the class group, Shafarevich explains how to identify points of the elliptic curve with a subgroup of the class group of the curve. You can therefore "transfer" the group structure from the class group onto the curve itself. This construction is in full generality, and the explanations are fairly complete. Shafarevich also goes through the explicit formulas for a cubic in Weierstrass normal form (this part shows that the group law is given by rational formulas, which is significant); for this he does assume $\operatorname{char} k \neq 2,3$ "to simplify formulas".

I'm not sure if there is a way to construct the group law using the coordinate ring of the curve alone. It seems to me that any such method would result in the same type of tedious algebraic manipulations that you're seeking to avoid, but this is just speculation.

Comment: Thank you very much! I knew that there is another approach using divisors, but I am not familiar with these at all. Nevertheless this book looks interesting! I will have a look at it tomorrow.

Comment: Regarding to your last paragraph: I don't expect a definition of the group law coming from the coordinate ring, but there surely is an elegant algebraic way to establish all these geometric statements (existence of certain lines, intersection numbers...) so that the definition of the group law and a large part of the associativity proof can be stated in purely geometric terms. This is what I am looking for.

Comment: @Dune, you'll have to look into the divisor approach to see if it is the elegant method that you seek =) Learning about divisors first will take a little time, but divisors are good objects to be familiar with anyway, and studying them with the group law as concrete motivation might help you to develop a feeling for them.

Comment: The problem with the divisors approach is that it is not immediate that the addition is an algebraic operation on $E(k)$.

Answer (score 1):

One can give a proof in terms of the "chord--tangent law" (i.e. the explicit description of the group operation via intersecting lines etc.) that avoids computation.

Basically, one uses Bezout's theorem, together with a limiting argument in the Zariski topology to cover various degenerate configurations.

I think this is explained in Miles Reid's *Undergraduate algebraic geometry*.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will have a look at this book soon.